# link field template syntax / display link field as an image / devel dpm (D7)

Tags: theming, debugging

My link field is currently displaying as a URL as you can see [here](http://test-090514.desertfish.co.uk/) (yellow border). I have added dpm($items) to my link field template file. How do I read the dpm output or more specifically how do I edit my template file to say "display this field as the specified image"?

The following example works in a different situation where the field is an uploaded file but in this case the field is a link.

```
<?php $path = $items[0]['#file']->uri; ?> 
<a href="<?php print file_create_url($path); ?>"><img src="../images/download.png"></a>
```

Comment: In the example with the yellow border, the URL is a file in mp3 format. Do you want to display a play option for the mp3?

Comment: @ Collins thanks for your reply - I am using a separate field for an MP3 player so my question here is about the red button here http://imgur.com/NGoKJMt ie click the button to download the MP3 file - which is a link to the MP3 file (as opposed to a file I have uploaded). In my example above I thought that #file referred to an uploaded file ie a different field and a different situation - will #file apply where the field is a URL link?

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what the problem is, If you are already outputting the link URL, and you want to display that as an image, surely you can just wrap it in an img tag?

```
<?php $path = $items[0]['#file']->uri; ?> 

<img src="<?php print file_create_url($path); ?>" />
```

OR, with an mp3 file like in your example...

```
<?php $path = $items[0]['#file']->uri; ?> 
<audio controls>
  <source src="<?php print file_create_url($path); ?>" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```